# SQLite Library - Python Portability

Tags: python, sqlite, portability

I am writing some code that is intended to operate with a pre-bundled version of Python included with a program.
The issue is that it doesn't as yet include the Sqlite3 library which is a requirement of my code. Currently I have a wrapped that calls a system installed version of python2.7 to use the import.

Is there any way I can manually include or package this library to go with the code to make it more portable? My concern is that I require this to operate on Windows systems but it is less likely that they will have python2.7 available. (2.7 is the minimum as this included an update to the library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in python you have [setup tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). You can use requirements.txt file and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install dependency.

[pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.0.2)  link

Answer (score 0):

[pysqlite](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/) is also maintained as an external project, looks like they've got [downloads](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/downloads/list) all the way back to Python 2.3